# Why can't my pyinstaller executable access data files?

Tags: pygame, conda, pyinstaller

I've been reading dozens of posts, including the pyinstaller docs, and cannot figure out why my pyinstaller executable keeps returning `pygame.error: Couldn't open data/items/switch.png`.

`switch.png` is the first of many images the script should be loading.

I'm running `pyinstaller --add-data 'data:data' snake.py` from the root directory of my application.  the only things in this director are `snake.py` and `data` where `data` contains subfolders for image and music files.

`snake.spec` shows `datas=[('data', 'data')],` which looks right to me.

I've also tried this with the `--onefile` modifier and still get the same error every time.

UPDATE:

I've verified the files are in the bundle. I'm using `--onedir` to troubleshoot this, and the directory structure within the `'Dist'` directory mirrors that of my native structure. Used `--add-data="data:data"` and there is a single 'Data' folder alongside the main .py file which contains one data file `'database.xlsx'` and subdirectories for the remaining data files. I'm receiving the following message which indicates the system cannot access the first data file:

```
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cronga.py", line 559, in <module>
  File "pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
  File "pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 824, in __init__
  File "pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 21, in __init__
  File "pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 353, in __init__
  File "pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 36, in load_workbook
  File "xlrd/__init__.py", line 111, in open_workbook
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/database.xlsx'
[11168] Failed to execute script cronga
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

Comment: Maybe you can log the output of `os.getcwd()` when your executable starts.  I'm guessing (assuming your exe packed correctly) that it's running from a different directory to where it's unpacked.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details, can you print `os.path.abspath(path_to_your_data_file)` 
 to check if the file exists? Have you used `sys._MEIPASS` as suggested below? A [mcve] will make it easier to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

What does your .spec file look like? Here's the [PyInstaller docs on adding data files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec-files.html#adding-data-files).

Basically you need to add something like:

```
a = Analysis(...
 datas=[ ('the.wav', '.') ],
 ...
 )
```

This will put your sound file ('the.wav') into the root directory of your compiled application (the second argument, '.'). From your question, it looks like you want to copy your entire data directory. The issue will be with the relative path of those files.

Then in your application you can check if you're running from source or as a compiled executable. I use a helper function:

```
def my_path(path_name):
    """Return the appropriate path for data files based on execution context"""
    if getattr( sys, 'frozen', False ):
        # running in a bundle
        return(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, path_name))
    else:
        # running live
        return path_name
```

So then your application code will look something like:

```
the_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(my_path("the.wav"))
```

When trying to debug your executables, it can help to open a command line and run your executable from there, if you've created a console application, then you may still see a traceback that occurs.

Comment: so i've tried the helper file (both yours and others I found in my research), and it is still unable to open the files from the executable. do i also need to manually add the files/directories to the Analysis class in the .spec file?

Comment: The documentation states "You can add data files to the bundle by using the `--add-data` command option, or by adding them as a list to the spec file" so either approach can work. It is difficult to assist you further without additional information from you. Have you verified that the files are being included in your bundle? Have you printed the paths to verify that your program is trying to load files from the correct location? Please update your question with more details of your diagnostic efforts.