# Im trying to turn a python file into an exe file and its not working

Tags: python, pygame, exe, pyinstaller

I tried making my python file into an exe using `pyinstaller main.py --onefile --noconsole`
.I was getting an error when I tried opening the exe from dist so i used `--debug=all` and it said `pyinstaller: error: the following arguments are required: scriptname`.

What exactly do i do im not too sure as its my first time.

Comment: It sounds like the problem you're having is with accessing the data files. If you remove the `--noconsole` option and run the executable from a command line, you'll be able to see the error trace. There's an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62528860/7675174) with a little more information on data files that you may find useful.

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve] so it's possible to assist you.

Answer (score -1):

To convert a python file to exe:

1. Make sure you have pyinstaller installed and up to date

   `pip install pyinstaller`
2. in PowerShell type the following:

   `pyinstaller --onefile -w 'youfilename.py'`

The file name should come out as `1.exe`
Make sure are in the right directory

If you have more doubts use this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/

Comment: ive done exactly this and i also put all my images and everything into `dist` folder where the exe is but im just getting this error when i try open it `Failed to execute script main`

Comment: Try                                                                                                                          .\pyinstaller --onefile -w 'yourfilename.py'                                                                                                               if that also does not work give the whole directory address of pyinstaller then type the command

Comment: Ive done this but i still keep getting the error `Failed to execute main script ` when I try opening the exe

Comment: Do you have any assets in your code? Like images or files. If so make sure you give the full path in the python code. For example "image = 'FULL PATH' "                                                  Sometimes if the .exe program Is not able to find it then it throws an exeption

Comment: check the following link to see how to add paths to your files: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle

Comment: Yes I do have assets in my code and I went to the website and it is just confusing me

Comment: I see this means that the .exe program cant point to your assets. To fix this make sure you give a full path then make the .exe file again. This should fix the problem.

Comment: There is no command. In your string when you point to the file "C:\......" just make sure the path here is right.