# How do I include assets on pyinstaller such as images and music

Tags: python, cmd, pygame, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaller to make my file an exe but every time i opened the exe it gave me an error saying `Failed to execute main script`. I tried many things and asked others and came to the conclusion its not identifying the assets. So how do i get it do identify the assets so i can make the exe run.

This is my code import pygame

```
import random
import math
import time

from pygame import mixer


pygame.init()
                                 #width, height
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))
background = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\35387\Documents\Python Coding\Shoot Deannes\back.png")

mixer.music.load(r"C:\Users\35387\Documents\Python Coding\Shoot Deannes\Song.mp3")
mixer.music.play(-1)

title = pygame.display.set_caption("Shoot Deannes")

icon = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\35387\Documents\Python Coding\Shoot Deannes\Deanne GYypsu python.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

lov = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\35387\Documents\Python Coding\Shoot Deannes\Lov.png")
show_image = False

playerImg = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\35387\Documents\Python Coding\Shoot Deannes\Python Player.png")
playerX = 450
playerY = 580
playerX_change = 0
playerY_change = 0

enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 5

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\35387\Documents\Python Coding\Shoot Deannes\Pygame Enemy D.png"))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 935))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(40, 140))
    enemyX_change.append(1.5)
    enemyY_change.append(random.uniform(0.3, 0.8))

bulletImg = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\35387\Documents\Python Coding\Shoot Deannes\Shoot.png")
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 0
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 7
bullet_state = "ready"

score_value = 0

font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 32)
textX = 20
textY = 20

def show_score(x, y):
    score = font.render("Landed shots :" + str(score_value), True, (255, 192, 203))
    screen.blit(score, (x, y))

def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

def enemy(x, y, i ):
    screen.blit(enemyImg[i], (x, y))

def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 16, y + 10))  

def isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemyX - bulletX,2)) + (math.pow(enemyY - bulletY,2))
    if distance < 50:
        return True
    else: 
        return False

def isCollision2(enemyX, enemyY, playerX, playerY):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemyX - playerX,2)) + (math.pow(enemyY - playerY,2))
    if distance < 70:
        return True
    else: 
        return False             

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -3.5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 3.5      
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bullet_state is "ready":
                    bullet_sound = mixer.Sound(r"C:\Users\35387\Documents\Python Coding\Shoot Deannes\ORG.wav")
                    bullet_sound.play()
                    bulletX = playerX 
                    bulletY = playerY
                    fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)         


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0  
        

                
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY_change = 2.5
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY_change = -2.5        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY_change = 0  
    
        
    playerX += playerX_change
    playerY += playerY_change
    if playerX <=0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >=935:
        playerX = 935   

    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
        enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
        if enemyX[i] <=0:
            enemyX_change[i] = 1.5
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
        elif enemyX[i] >=935:
            enemyX_change[i] = -1.5
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
   
        collision = isCollision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
        if collision:
            bulletY = 580
            bullet_state = "ready"
            score_value += 1
            enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 1000)
            enemyY[i] = random.randint(40, 140)   
        
        collision2 = isCollision2(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], playerX, playerY)
        if collision2:
            playerX = 4000
            playerY = 4000
            gameover_sound = mixer.Sound(r"C:\Users\35387\Documents\Python Coding\Shoot Deannes\GAME OVER.wav") 
            gameover_sound.play()
            show_image = True

        if show_image:
            pygame.display.set_mode((480, 910)).blit(lov, (0, 0))
       

        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)                  

    if bulletY <=0 :
        bulletY =580
        bullet_state = "ready"

    if bullet_state is "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)    
        bulletY -= bulletY_change


    player(playerX, playerY)
    show_score(textX, textY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

This also my first time doing this type of stuff, so please dont mind my dumbness. Ive all assets and this file which is called main.py in the same folder and i cannot successfully make it into an exe.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is in the way you're handling resource paths and how you're loading them. Looks at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62528860/7675174) for some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Put the assets in the same folder as the executable. (Or, if it expects the assets in a subfolder, put them there)

Comment: @Jeromus your code and folder structure would be helpful to know then

Comment: ok so do you need my full code, but anyways in my folder there is a few pgns, a wav file and an mp3. 


`

Comment: @Jeromus yeah your code would be helpful as well as how the folder the executable is in is set up

Comment: Ok ill put in the code and what exactly do you mean the exe is in a `dist` folder

Comment: @Jeromus I mean where you put the assets compared to where the executable is

Comment: Yeah i dont totally understand but i copied the the original assets and put them in the dist folder beside the exe and it still wouldnt work

Comment: @Jeromus ok, I see the problem. You have absolute paths when you should use relative paths. Try deleting the `C:\Users\35387\Documents\Python Coding\Shoot Deannes\` part of the file paths to make them relative.

Comment: Ok so i replaced them with the relative paths and tried making the exe but im still getting the error failed to execute script main