# PyInstaller fatal error: Failed to execute script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-imaging-library, pyinstaller

First of all, I want to apologize for the very long question but this is driving me crazy. Saturday I have to exhibit this project to my school's open day and I have little to no time.

I've written a snake game in Python 3.9 with a friend (using Pygame) and I'm trying to create an executable file with PyInstaller from it (using multiple python modules and additional files such as images and music), but every time I execute the command `pyinstaller Game.spec` and I try to run the executable I get this error:

[image: PyInstaller error window]

This error is very unexpected and strange to me because I already made it executable about a week ago (but it was an older version and we change lots of things) in the same way and it worked flawlessly, but now it won't work in any way, we tried everything and read every post here on Stack, so the executable gets created but it won't start.

## GIF Converter Module

We changed really a lot of things since we made the first executable, but the structure of the code remained pretty much the same with the only exception of a module that I wrote, basically it automatically splits animated GIFs into separated frames and loads them into Pygame (loading every single frame by hand was too time-wasting...). I suspect that this module might be one of the causes that ultimately lead to prompting that error every time I try to execute the game. We used this module to animate the buttons in the main menu:

[image: pyWormy menu]

### How does it work?

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
import os
import pygame  

class PyGimager:
def __init__(self, gif):
    # Loading the desired gif image
    self.gif = Image.open(gif)

    # Variable where all the frames will be stored
    self.frames = []

    self.assetFrames_url = []

# This method divides all the frames of the gif in a .png file (in a desired folder)
def deconstructGif(self, mainName='decImage', savePath='LOCAL'):
    path = savePath + "/" + mainName
    self.assetFrames_url.append(resource_path(path))
    local = True

    if savePath != 'LOCAL':
        try:
            os.makedirs(savePath)
        except OSError as error:
            print("Path creation failed: {}".format(error))
        local = False

    for i in range(self.gif.n_frames):
        self.gif.seek(i)
        if not local:
            self.gif.save(savePath + mainName + '{}.png'.format(i), 'PNG')
        else:
            self.gif.save(mainName + '{}.png'.format(i))

# loads all the frames in a bidimensional array
def gifLoader(self, loadPath="/"):
    frame = ''
    if loadPath == "/":
        for image in os.listdir():
            if image.endswith(".png"):
                frame = pygame.image.load(image)
                self.frames.append(frame)
    else:
        for image in os.listdir(loadPath):
            if image.endswith(".png"):
                frame = pygame.image.load(loadPath + image)
                self.frames.append(frame)

def gifPlayer(self, screen, position=def_position, wait=500):
    for frame in self.frames:
        AnimatedSprite = frame
        screen.blit(AnimatedSprite, position)
        pygame.time.wait(wait)
        pygame.display.update()

def getFirstFrame(self):
    return self.frames[0]
```

Sorry for the messy code but I had to learn OOP in about 3 days to write all of this and I am still a bit confused. Anyway, the attributes of the class are pretty much self-explanatory, `gif` contains the desired animated image given by the user, the `frames` array will contain all the images extracted from the animated gif while `assetFrames_url` is a copy of `frames` containing the relative paths, we used it to bypass another bug in PyInstaller which didn't allow us to add our files to `Game.spec`, so we had to pass through this function all the additional files, here's the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790741/13216957) of this function.

We had to write by hand (I tried to automate it with a script but it was a huge failure) the path of every single additional element inside `Game.spec`. With the method `deconstructGif` the gif gets split (one image for each frame) in a specific folder, then all the split frames are loaded inside the `frames` array with the `gifLoader` method and finally they get animated with the method `gifPlayer`.

For example, these are the folders of the animated buttons:

[image: Buttons]

## Game.spec

When we compiled the first executable we had to manually insert the path for each file inside an array of tuples. This is the last version:

```
        # -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['Game.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\gianm\\Documents\\GitKraken\\pyWormy'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[
             ('Img/Buttons/Hard/HardButton0.png','Img/Buttons/Hard/'),('Img/Buttons/Hard/HardButton1.png','Img/Buttons/Hard/'),
             ('Img/Buttons/Easy/EasyButton0.png','Img/Buttons/Easy/'),('Img/Buttons/Easy/EasyButton1.png','Img/Buttons/Easy/'),
             ('Img/Buttons/Options/OptionsButton0.png','Img/Buttons/Options/'),('Img/Buttons/Options/OptionsButton1.png','Img/Buttons/Options/'),
             ('Img/Buttons/Play/PlayButton0.png','Img/Buttons/Play/'),('Img/Buttons/Play/PlayButton1.png','Img/Buttons/Play/'),
             ('Img/Buttons/Exit/ExitButton0.png','Img/Buttons/Exit/'),('Img/Buttons/Exit/ExitButton1.png','Img/Buttons/Exit/'),
             ('Img/Buttons/BackToMenu/BacktoMenuButton0.png','Img/Buttons/BackToMenu/'),('Img/Buttons/BackToMenu/BacktoMenuButton1.png','Img/Buttons/BackToMenu/'),
             ('SF_Pixelate.ttf','.'),
             ('Sounds/difficileSottofondo.wav','Sounds/'),('Sounds/facileSottofondo.wav','Sounds/'),('Sounds/lose.wav','Sounds/'),('Sounds/slurp.wav','Sounds/'),('Sounds/musica.wav','Sounds/'),
             ('Img/background.png','Img/'),('Img/GameOver.png','Img/'),('Img/startMenu.png','Img/'), 
             ('Img/Sprites/Sprites3/CorpoSerpente.png','Img/Sprites/Sprites3/'),
             ('Img/Sprites/Sprites3/TestaDestra.png','Img/Sprites/Sprites3/'), ('Img/Sprites/Sprites3/TestaGiu.png','Img/Sprites/Sprites3/'),('Img/Sprites/Sprites3/TestaSinistra.png','Img/Sprites/Sprites3/'),('Img/Sprites/Sprites3/TestaSopra.png','Img/Sprites/Sprites3/'),
             ('Img/Sprites/Sprites3/Mela/C.png','Img/Sprites/Sprites3/Mela/'),('Img/Sprites/Sprites3/Mela/Ruby.png','Img/Sprites/Sprites3/Mela/'),('Img/Sprites/Sprites3/Mela/PHP.png','Img/Sprites/Sprites3/Mela/'),('Img/Sprites/Sprites3/Mela/JS.png','Img/Sprites/Sprites3/Mela/'), 
             ('Img/Buttons/Hard.gif','Img/Buttons/'),('Img/Buttons/Easy.gif','Img/Buttons/'),('Img/Buttons/Options.gif','Img/Buttons/'),('Img/Buttons/Exit.gif','Img/Buttons/'), 
             ('Img/Buttons/BackToMenu.gif','Img/Buttons/'),('Img/Buttons/Play.gif','Img/Buttons/'),  
             
             ],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='pyWormy',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False , icon='Icon.ico')
```

Inside the `datas` array, I inserted a tuple for each file, the first argument is the relative path of the image while the second is the relative path of the folder. The local paths are represented by a point ('.').

## Things I've tried:

- First of all, I tried to locate the "source" of the problem, so I opened the `.spec` file generated with the execution of the command `pyinstaller -i Icon.Ico --onefile Game.py` (with Ico.ico being the icon of the executable and Game.py the main module) and I activated the console debug, like this:

  ```
             console=True, icon='Icon.ico')
  ```

This is the error that i get in detail:

[image: CMD error]

- I tried to pass in the data array the path for all the frames, it didn't work.
- I tried to pass in the paths of all the GIFs, it didn't work.

I apologize if this question may seem confusing and if the grammar is really bad but English is not my primary language and I need to fix this fast and I don't have time to correct all the mistakes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See if my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62528860/2280890) helps, you need a helper function to determine the path of the files included with your installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve this.

Basically, there is a compatibility issue between Pygame and PIL (Python Imaging Library), I had to rewrite the entire pyGimager class and I was not able to make a single executable file but in the end, it works.